# Retrieve localised value

Tags: theme-development, ajax

I have send ajax request

```
     wp_localize_script('fw-alt-block', 'ajax_custom', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('cr_ajax'),
    'loading' => __('Loading...', 'cr'),
    'catagory' => $catagory,
    ));
```

Upon inspecting the result is

```
var ajax_custom = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/localhost\/porto\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","nonce":"776c1e668c","loading":"Loading...","catagory":["3"]};
```

Now I want to retrieve the values again in functions.php. To get the value of catagory I have used

```
$catagory=$_POST['catagory'];
```

But I did not get the value.Is it possible or anything wrong in my code?

Comment: your ajax request has to send whatever data you want to access.

Comment: In jquery I can get variable in this way,ajax_custom.catagory.Is there any way to get this value in php?

Comment: You have to send it with your ajax request. The page you make your request from and the ajax request are two separate requests with no state maintained between the two. Edit your question and add the javascript code you are using to make the ajax request.